# insert into foreign key proper sql execution

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I found that my error caused by my PK doesn't have a value so my insertion on FK failed.

like table A uId is PK of table B's uId (FK), so if I want to insert 1 in table B's uId, the table A's uId must have the value of 1.

But is that 2 query execution? how it should be written? I tried 2 sql execution the second - where insert into FK, has failed.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Generally, if you don't know the foreign key ID (e.g. if the FK is a surrogate key), you will be able to look it up based on another (e.g. Natural) key. Also, remember that FK's can be NULLABLE, viz if the relationship between A and B is optional.

Comment: @StuartLC The relationship is there and I don't get why you say A and B optional. My problem is I can't insert into FK. I put 2 query in a file. the second failed because it seem doesn't recognize the first, which I inserted a value into table A's PK.

Comment: Is by any chance TABLE A's PK an `IDENTITY`, i.e. do you need to find the ID of the recently inserted A ID so that you can use it for an insert into B? If not, you would have had to provide the PK for A when you inserted into A, so you should know the A ID.

Comment: oic. so I shouldn't insert by using the same variable? instead, I should select the inserted PK. For example like this "insert into tableA(`uId`) values("select uId from tableA")??

Answer (score 0):

I've put the 3 methods discussed in the comments into a [SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2ccf9/2)

```
-- Null Foreign Key, if the relationship is optional
INSERT INTO B(AID) VALUES(NULL);

-- Lookup - if you know of another `natural` column in table A, 
-- e.g. here we know the Name we need to link to
INSERT INTO B(AID) VALUES((SELECT AID FROM A WHERE AName = 'Foo'))

-- Identity Insert - when A and B are inserted at the same time, 
-- and you need to pass A ID to B
INSERT INTO A(AName) VALUES('Baz');
INSERT INTO B(AID) VALUES((SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()));

SELECT * FROM A;
SELECT * FROM B;
```

For MySql it is similar, just use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` vs `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: $stmt2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO usertabbrige(`tabId`,`uId`) VALUES ((LAST_INSERT_ID()),$userId)");


anything wrong?